# Please increase the size of the "Introduce yourself"

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, design

I looked at this recently and asked myself if there is any good reason for this to be only three lines high? Says so in the HTML `rows="3"`. But it is odd, because in the past (looking at the similar questions) it was a resizable before and now it isn't anymore.

It is pretty hard to read/write a cover letter with only three lines visible.

[image: Current Introduce yourself text box]